# Which logging library to use for cross-language (Java, C++, Python) system

Tags: java, c++, python, logging

I have a system where a central Java controller launches analysis processes, which may be written in C++, Java, or Python (mostly they are C++). All these processes currently run on the same server. What are you suggestions to

- Create a central log to which all processes can write to
- What if in the future I push some processes to another server. How can I support distributed logging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache has [cross-platform logging libraries](http://logging.apache.org/), which allow you to log from various programming languages using similar APIs.  Unfortunately they don't have a Python API, though you should be able to whip one up with log4cpp and Boost.Python.

A project I work on uses one of these libraries to log to a database, which allows us "distributed logging" with a centralized place for the log messages.  I have to admit I'm not a fan of this.  Another project I work on uses one of these libraries to log to the native logging facility.  The Windows Event Log has some features for distributed logging, but AFAIK syslog does not.

Although I don't have any experience with it, a better fit may be [Facebook's Scribe](http://github.com/facebook/scribe) project.  The feature set meets your requirements, including a Python API.  Unfortunately it uses Thrift which doesn't work for C++ on Windows (that is, the Thrift compiler generates C++ code that only works on UNIX).  You may be able to get around this problem using Cygwin, but I can't promise that approach will work.

Comment: syslog supports distributed logging.  The classic syslogd supports forwarding messages to another host with the `@hostname` syntax.  See "Remote Machine" section in the syslog.conf man page: http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using the platform's native logger which is syslog on Posix and Event Log on Windows.

For C++, you can use the native calls on the platform.

I know Python comes with syscall wrapper on Posix and there are wrappers for Event Log in the [PyWin32 extension](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/).  I assume that someone has created Java wrappers by now.

**Update**

Regarding syslog and multiple files.  syslog support the concept of facilities - via facilities you can have different logs go to different files.  Unfortunatley, facilities are predefined; while there are 8 generic ones `LOG_LOCAL0` through `LOG_LOCAL7` you cannot define arbitrary facilities.

Also note that it's up to the syslog daemon to decide where to route log messages for each facility / level.  You may need to adjust your syslog daemon configuration to have each facility get sent to a different file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you create separate syslog logs on the same machine? We have different services, each with a number of processes and we want to keep the logs separate ideally.

Comment: @recipriversexclusion - updated answer to answer your comment.

Comment: Another nice thing about syslog is that all reasonable implementations already know how to send log messages across the network to another machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **Apache log4cxx or Apache log4j**.
It's Efficient. It has Logger hierarchies to modularize your logs. It's proven tecnology for a  while now.
Currently, appenders exist for the console , files , GUI components, remote socket servers, NT Event Loggers , and remote UNIX Syslog daemons. It is also possible to log asynchronously.

How can I support distributed logging? 
With remote socket servers appenders for example.